# Need help understanding Callsite arrays in Groovy

Tags: groovy, call

I came across this piece of code when looking at an application.

```
groovy.util.ConfigObject config = (groovy.util.ConfigObject)org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(arrayOfCallSite[438].callGetProperty(this.grailsApplication), groovy.util.ConfigObject.class);
```

My question are, what does a callsite array do and how is it initialized to contain the data to be retrieved later on?(In this case the config)I tried reading the documentation for groovy but there is no useful description at all explaining what it does and only a list of methods and attributes is shown in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like decompiled  groovy code or generated java code from groovy.

Let's see the simple groovy script:

```
cfg = new ConfigObject()
ConfigObject c = cfg
```

The line with assignment of script variable `cfg` value into local type defined `c` variable in java will look like:

```
ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(localObject, Script61235.class, this, (String)"cfg");
ConfigObject c = (ConfigObject)ScriptBytecodeAdapter
    .castToType(arrayOfCallSite[2].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), ConfigObject.class)
```

so, your code approximately corresponds to this groovy code:

```
ConfigObject config = this.grailsApplication.xxx
```

where `xxx` we don't see in your question.

better to find original groovy code and you will understand it better )

Comment: Does this mean that Callsite Arrays are never used directly by a developer? It is true that I got the code above from decompiling the class files because it is not open source.

Comment: as I know it's not possible to use `arrayOfCallSite` from plain groovy code. but that's not 100% ))